# Arduino Mega, ST7920 using COSA

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd, st7920

I am trying to learn and understand the [COSA Library](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa) using a 12864ZW (ST7920) 128X64 LCD Display. Right now I am able to use the LCD using the u8glib but also found that COSA has a library for the [ST7920 Display](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/993383/Cosa/doc/html/dir_6c9b05e5d5923c236f9de149d085166d.html), I originally used [this tutorial](http://overskill.alexshu.com/128x64-12864-lcd-w-arduino-serial/) to get things working.

The main problem that I have now is in the [ST7920 Documentation](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/libraries/ST7920/ST7920.hh) there is a schematic that shows how to hook up a ST7920 Compatible LCD. The first [tutorial](http://overskill.alexshu.com/128x64-12864-lcd-w-arduino-serial/) only uses 3 lines from the Mega and the Cosa is using what looks like 6 lines.

Looking at the header file, it looks like it is derived from the HD44780 Class and what I can gather is pins 16 and 4 are hard coded for something? I am not quite clear on how to use the Cosa version of the library. Can someone please give me a explanation and perhaps a explanation on how to get this working using Cosa?

Answer (score 1):

The Cosa ST7920 library uses text mode only (16X4). The ST7920 class is controlled though an adapter. There are several adapters available depending on how you wish to connect to the Arduino. They range from parallel 4-bit to SPI with shift register. The adapters implement the interface [HD44780::IO](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/libraries/HD44780/HD44780.hh#L44). There are several LCD examples. The [CosaLCDbench](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/libraries/LCD/CosaLCDbench/CosaLCDbench.ino) shows the possible configurations with LCD and Adapters. Please see the file for further details.

Comment: I saw that there are many examples but I can not for the life of me get this to compile, I opened another question at http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18358/eclipse-add-library. I see that you are on the GIT for COSA can you give me any advise to get this to compile?